# xcode 4.2 crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

today i tried to run my first iPhone app(the app is assignment in Stanford course).
in the assignment i ask to defining and instantiating class in interface builder, i defined the class run the simulator and everything work just fine. when i tried to connect the class(and the object) to the UI and then run the simulator xcode was crashed and show this message:

```
Thread 1:signal sigABRT
```

when i remove the connection between the class to the UI(i remove the connection between the outlets and the label in the app view) everything is again work fine.
i tried to understand where the problem came from with breakpoints and the crash is in this line of code(in the main file):

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

pls help me, it's make me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4.x is not very good at telling you where the real error is and shows that line in main.m instead.  Try replacing it with code that shows you more information:

```
@try {
  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
  NSLog(@"Exception %@\n%@", [exception description], [exception callStackSymbols]);
}
```